# Prove the automorphism given by $\phi \left(g\right)=\left(g^{-1}\right)^t$ is not an inner automorphism of $SL_n\left(R\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

Prove the automorphism given by $\phi \left(g\right)=\left(g^{-1}\right)^t$ is not an inner automorphism of $SL_n\left(R\right)$

Having no success with this question, I turn for your help =]

I considered that adjugate matrices have same determinant - but still, I couldn't find the solution...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I included your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An inner automorphism will preserve the spectrum of matrices. If you look at some diagonal matrix like
$$\mathrm{Diag}(2,2,\dots,2,2^{-(n-1)})$$
then the transpose of its inverse has a different spectrum, at least for $n>2$. For the $n=2$ case I'm not immediately sure how to proceed.

**EDIT** As @JyrkiLahtonen points out, the statement is false for $n=2$. There is an explicit formula for $\phi$ given by
$$\phi\left(\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}d&-c\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}$$
And as he points out, this is conjugation by $\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: The difference with $n=2$ and $n>2$ can be explained also in terms of Dynkin diagrams. The automorphism $\phi$ is known to correspond to the non-trivial graph automorphism of diagrams of type $A_{n-1}$. This is the identity graph automorphism on the one-point diagram $A_1$ corresponding to $SL_2$. IIRC in general the automorphisms of Chevalley groups and algebraic groups are combinations of an inner automorphism, a field automorphism and a graph automorphism. My upvote was there as soon as I saw your answer.